# C++ Visual Studio 2012 WM_SIZE -> SIZE_MAXIMIZED only works once

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2012, wndproc

I'm currently programming the GUI for my game and I've ran into a problem. When the user resizes the window with the maximize button or by double clicking the top a WM_SIZE is generated and sent to the WndProcedure. The problem is, the message SIZE_MAXIMIZED in wParam only works when making the window bigger, not smaller. What's the other way around? SIZE_RESTORED won't do it because that is generated when the user grabs the edges which I handle in WM_SIZING.

Comment: When the user grabs the edges, the window is no longer maximized. Generating `SIZE_MAXIMIZED` would be incorrect. Can you be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem with `SIZE_MAXIMIZED` here. Window is maximized only when it actively fills entire desktop area, minimized when it's collapsed to taskbar and restored when it's in floating state. If you want to tell if window became larger or smaller, you should check new client area size vs the old one.

Comment: @Billy ONeal To make it clearer, I want to know what the opposite message to SIZE_MAXIMIZED is when dealing with the maximize button because it isn't generated when pressing it to scale the window back to its original shape it had before maximizing. The SIZE_RESTORED won't do as described because that is generated when pulling the edges of the window. And I deal with that in WM_SIZING.

Comment: @TobiasSundell So you want to know when window stops being maximized? You could make a bool that you set to true when you get WM_SIZE with SIZE_MAXIMIZED and false when you get WM_SIZE with SIZE_RESTORED. If when changing it to false it was previously set to true it would mean the window has just become "unmaximized". I don't think there is a direct message for this.

Comment: That answered my question. Thank you.

Comment: Strange question.  How does the user change the size of a maximized window, other than by restoring it?  You should *not* allow resizing when the window is maximized.

Comment: @Tobias: When the user grabs the edge of the window, that is "restoring" the window. The message is correct, and your program should behave accordingly.

Comment: My tests show that SIZE_RESTORED is generated both when double-clicking the title bar of a maximised window or restoring via the window's system menu, from either maximized or minimized states.

Comment: Once I had a similar problem. Actually many window position/change messages are just synthesized messages as a result of `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED`. Try to check out and hook the `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` event as this is the mother of all. I've played around with this even quite long ago and as far as I know it has some undocumented flags too related to minimized/maximized state changes... Also: `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` and the events synthesized from it and the order of these events may vary between windows versions and even on the same windows with different window managers (classic/aero)...